# Share the same encoder setting for different appenders in logback xml

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging, logback, logstash-logback-encoder

I have an encoder using `net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder` to configure the log content via a mix of stock providers, patterns and custom providers. The same is to be used in different appenders, e.g. console, file, rolling file and a custom one for unit testing. I don't want to repeat the same configuration in every appender as it is exactly the same, so I wonder if there is a way to share it across different appenders?

e.g.

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="FILE_LOG" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
      ... configuration can be shared ...
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
      ... repeated the exact same configuration ...
    </encoder>
  </appender>
```

I know there is this "include" feature, but it seems it has to start from the root level (i.e. `appender`) for inclusion. Is there a way to "include" at the `encoder` level?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, logback does not provide a way to share encoder configuration completely in xml configuration files.

Instead, you could

1. define a class that extends `net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder`,
2. perform configuration programmatically within that class, and then
3. reference your class in the xml.

For example:

```java
public class JsonEncoder extends LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder {
    public JsonEncoder() {
    }
    @Override
    public void start() {
        // Note: you can access logback properties via getContext().getProperty(...)

        JsonProviders<ILoggingEvent> providers = getProviders();
        providers.addProvider(new LoggingEventFormattedTimestampJsonProvider());
        providers.addProvider(new LogLevelJsonProvider());
        providers.addProvider(new MessageJsonProvider());
        providers.addProvider(new ThreadNameJsonProvider());
        providers.addProvider(new LoggerNameJsonProvider());
        providers.addProvider(new MdcJsonProvider());
        providers.addProvider(new LogstashMarkersJsonProvider());
        providers.addProvider(new StackTraceJsonProvider());
        providers.addProvider(new ArgumentsJsonProvider());
        super.start();
    }
}
```

```xml
<configuration>
  <appender name="FILE_LOG" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <encoder class="your.package.JsonEncoder"/>
  </appender>
  <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="your.package.JsonEncoder"/>
  </appender>
```

You could also ditch the `logback.xml` and go to a full programmatic configuration, where you would use a factory method to create each encoder.  Note that separate encoder instances are required for each appender, but you could construct each encoder instance identically.

Also, I haven't tried it personally, but you might be able to use the [groovy configuration](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/groovy.html) to share encoder configuration, but that unfortunately requires adding groovy to your classpath.

Comment: Yes thank you. I guess you are right, but would love to wait a bit and see if there is other answer (like using groovy you mentioned) from others before accepting that "there is no way to do it in pure xml" as the answer. Also, doing it in program loses the ease of config change. But credit to you for your effort to show that possibility to everyone, kudos.